# Crystal reports 11 RDC (COM API) displays printer dialog even when I tell it not to prompt

Tags: com, printing, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm using Crystal Reports 11's RDC (COM) API to print. My code looks like this:

```
HRESULT res = m_Report->SelectPrinter(b_driver, b_device, b_port);
if (FAILED(res)) return res;
// For these calls, the #import wrapper throws on error
m_Report->PutPrinterDuplex(dmDuplex);
m_Report->PutPaperSize(dmPaperSize);
m_Report->PutPaperSource((CRPaperSource)pdlg->GetDevMode()->dmDefaultSource);
if (m_Report->GetPaperOrientation() == crDefaultPaperOrientation)
    m_Report->PutPaperOrientation(crPortrait);

VARIANT vfalse;
VariantInit(&vfalse);
vfalse.vt=VT_BOOL;
vfalse.boolVal=0;

res = m_Report->PrintOut(vfalse);
```

However, at the end of all this, crystal reports still shows its own printer selection dialog - but only for some reports, it seems. Why does crystal reports show a print dialog even when I pass false for `promptUser`? And how, then, can I suppress crystal reports' internal printer selection dialog and force it to use my values?

Edit: Whoops, CR11, not CR9.

Some further information:

- The reports that work properly (ie, do not show the print dialog) are generated internally using the RDC API; we create a new report object, import subreports into it, then print the result. No problem there.
- The reports that *do not* work properly (ie, force the print dialog to open) have been created with a previous version of crystal reports; however, opening and saving the report does not seem to help.
- Sample reports in the Crystal Reports installation directory show the same problem.

I tried reproducing with VBScript; however, the result was that nothing was printed at all (no dialog, no nothing):

```
Set app = CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application.11")
Set report = app.OpenReport("C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Crystal Reports 11.5\Samples\en\Reports\General Business\Inventory Crosstab.rpt")
report.PrintOut(True)
rem Testing with a True parameter to force a print dialog - but no printout and nothing appears (no error either though)
```

Comment: by 'opening and saving the report' do you mean using the RDC or the IDE (crw32.exe)?  could you try opening, *refreshing*, then saving the 'old' report with the RDC, then do the same with the original 'old' report with the IDE?  any differences?

Comment: @craig, What do you mean by Refreshing? There's no `Refresh` method on the Report object afaics

Comment: @bdonlan, sorry, that's the term used in the IDE.  My goal is to have crystal (both versions (IDE & RDC), so 2 tests) load data into the RPT to see if that resets any internal flags (or wahtever) that might be causing this.  realistically, this seems like a bug--have you checked for hotfixes or services patches for the RDC?  Another option, assuming that we can't get this working, would be to export the report in PDF format, then print that.

Comment: @craig, this won't be the first time I've dealt with bugs in the RDC - I have some ugly patches elsewhere for another unrelated problem :) Unfortunately, this is the latest service pack, and upstream's moved on to the .NET API for future releases - unfortunately we're not able to migrate yet. I'll give your suggestion a shot; if that fails, I'll just have to patch out `PrintDlgExW` in-memory :)

Comment: @bdonian, how the hell does one 'just have to patch out PrintDlgExW in-memory'?  for sanity sake, you may want to migrate to MSRS.  you might find this project useful: http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/downloads/list

Comment: @craig, thanks for the link. In the future we may be able to do something cleaner, but we're up against time pressure right now and patching out PrintDlgExW is something that I _know_ will work and can be done relatively quickly :) Anything .NET isn't an option right now, unfortunately.

Comment: @craig, also, what do you mean by MSRS? Googling isn't coming up with anything much relevant

Comment: @bdonlan, i meant microsoft reporting services.  the project that i referenced is a way to convert a RPT to its XML equivalent.  you see when i'm going with this...

Comment: @craig, I do, and as I said .NET isn't an option for us right now, unfortunately. Neither is a dependency on SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in my code after all - I'd previously put in a wrapper for the RDC API to fix certain other bugs we were having; due to the large number of methods in the IReport interfaces, I wrote a script to generate pass-through stubs for the methods I wasn't interested in. Turns out that script was passing in bogus values for parameters with default values. Oops! Fixing the wrapper code fixed the bug here.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me preface that I'm not a C/C++ programmer, so I'm not able to test the code--my interaction w/ the SDK has been with the VB and .Net interface over the years.

I found the following code from BO's [devlibrary](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/devsuite.htm#en/RDC_SDK/rdc_com_dg_doc/doc/rdcsdk_com_doc/RDC_ObjectModel164.html):

```
// A dummy variant
VariantInit (&dummy);
dummy.vt = VT_EMPTY;
HRESULT       hr = S_OK;
// Specify the path to the report you want to print                                    
_bstr_t ReportPath("c:\\Program Files\\Business Objects\\Crystal Reports 11.5\\Samples\\En\\Reports\\General Business\\Inventory.rpt");
_variant_t vtEmpty(DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);
// Instantiate the IApplication object
m_Application.CreateInstance("CrystalRuntime.Application.115");
//Open the Report using the OpenReport method
m_Report = m_Application->OpenReport(ReportPath, dummy)
//Print the Report to printer
m_Report->PrintOut(dummy, dummy, dummy, dummy);
```

Does it work?  It should print the report with its 'default' printer settings and without prompting.

You wrote:

> However, at the end of all this,
>   crystal reports still shows its own
>   printer selection dialog - but only
>   for some reports, it seems.

Generally speaking, I've found that Crystal tends to ignore commands to suppress dialogs if it thinks something is missing.  I've found this to be true with the parameter dialog.  Perhaps it apply to this situation as well.  I would ask what is different about the reports that cause the dialog to be generated.  There is a 'no printer' option that can be set.  Perhaps this is the common thread.

Do you have access to the VB6 IDE?  If you write the equivalent commands using VB6's interface, does the prompting occur?

You might also investigate using the CRPE32.dll instead of the report-designer control.  To be honest, I don't know if the RDC wraps the CRPE DLL or is an entirely-separate code base.

Comment: The code you posted (with corrections to the CLSID and report path) results in a print dialog being shown. I'll give the VB stuff a short shortly. As for the difference in reports, the reports that give the dialog were created in a previous version of crystal reports; the reports that _do not_ create the dialog were created using the RDC API in-memory from scratch (although importing other reports via the `ImportSubreport` call

Comment: Tried with VBScript, see my answer above. Also, initially my question title was off - I'm on CR11, not CR9 (the bug was introduced when we switched to CR11)

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty here even though the problem's not quite solved because of all the effort craig has put in to trying to help with the problem - thanks :)

Comment: i'm happy to help--i more than understand the frustration that can result from something that clearly should work, but doesn't.  thanks, for the award, even thought i'm not sure that my solution merits it.